# Convert numerical variables into factors when the number of levels is lower than a given threshold with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I want to convert numerical variables into factors when the number of levels is lower than a given threshold with dplyr.

This would be most useful with binary variables coded as numerical '0/1'.

example data:

```
threshold<-5

data<-data.frame(binary1=rep(c(0,1), 5), binary_2=sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = TRUE), multilevel=sample(c(1:4), 10, replace=TRUE), numerical=1:10)

> data
   binary1 binary_2 multilevel numerical
1        0        1          2         1
2        1        0          3         2
3        0        1          2         3
4        1        0          1         4
5        0        1          2         5
6        1        1          4         6
7        0        1          1         7
8        1        1          3         8
9        0        1          1         9
10       1        0          4        10

sapply(data, class)
   binary1   binary_2 multilevel  numerical 
 "numeric"  "numeric"  "integer"  "integer"
```

I could easily transform all variables into factors with mutate(), across() and where(), like this:

```
data<-data%>%mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.factor))

> sapply(data, class)
   binary1   binary_2 multilevel  numerical 
  "factor"   "factor"   "factor"   "factor"
```

However, I cant find a way to mutate with multiple conditions, including my threshold argument, for the where() function. I wanted to have this output:

```
sapply(data, class)
   binary1   binary_2 multilevel  numerical 
 "factor"  "factor"  "factor"  "integer"
```

Tried the following, but failed:

```
data%>%mutate(across(where(is.numeric & length(unique(.x))<threshold), as.factor))
```

error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x object '.x' not found
ℹ Input `..1` is `across(where(!is.factor & length(unique(.x)) < threshold), as.factor)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Maybe I don't understand across() and where() well enough.
Suggestions are welcomed.

Additional question:
why including a negation operator (!) before is.factor gets me an error when the version without (!) is perfectly fine?

```
data<-data%>%mutate(across(where(!is.factor), as.factor))
```

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x invalid argument type
ℹ Input `..1` is `across(where(!is.factor), as.factor)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an anonymous or lambda function in `where`.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>% 
     mutate(across(where(~is.numeric(.) && n_distinct(.) < threshold), factor))

sapply(data, class)

#   binary1   binary_2 multilevel  numerical 
#  "factor"   "factor"   "factor"  "integer"
```

To answer your additional question, `!is.factor` is not a function like `is.factor`. Use the function in the same way as above.

```
data %>% mutate(across(where(~!is.factor(.)), factor))
```

Comment: Why the double && instead of just &, @Ronak Shah?
And why does my method not work?

Comment: 1. `&` is for vectors and `&&` is for scalars. Although in this case it would work the same way but `&&` is safer and faster for scalar comparisons. 2. If you have any complex comparisons or operations which goes beyond the usage of basic function you need to use the lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data1 <- setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
        if(is.numeric(x) && uniqueN(x) < threshold) factor(x) else x)]
```